# TBalloonHint showing as default?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.1-berlin, balloon-tip

Create a VCL Forms Application, put a `TBalloonHint` and a `TButton` on the form and in the button's click-event handler write this code:

```
procedure TForm2.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if balloonhintTest.ShowingHint then
    ShowMessage('balloonhintTest is showing')
  else
    ShowMessage('balloonhintTest is not showing');
end;
```

Strangely, when clicking the button at runtime, this message is displayed:

[image]

...although it has never programmatically been shown with `balloonhintTest.ShowHint`.

The only way I found so far to prevent this is the following workaround:

```
procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  balloonhintTest.HideHint;
end;
```

So why the BalloonHint is reported as showing (while it is not physically showing at all) as default, and is there a better way to set this to False as default?

Comment: In the `TCustomHint` constructor, `FShow` is set to `True`: `FShow := True;`. Why? `TBalloonHint` is an object which is created together with the main form, not when it is shown.

Comment: The only other way I've found is using an "interposer" class: http://i.imgur.com/el7l9Zm.png Is this correct?

Comment: Sounds like a bug, did you [report it to Embarcadero](http://quality.embarcadero.com) yet?